# How can I set up a password-less AP with nmcli?

Tags: networking, wifi, nmcli, wifi-hotspot

I own a USB WiFi device which works well, until I try to connect to anything encrypted.

I want to use this USB device as an AP, ideally with `nmcli`. How do I do so?

All the sources I've  found, show clearly, how can I create a (WPA or WPA2) encrypted AP. I have found nothing to create an AP without any encryption.

Google is surprisingly silent in the topic.

Comment: What's the make/model of the device? More importantly, what does `lsusb` tell you about it?

Comment: Belkin usb, rtl8172u driver, works as not encrypted wifi client and that is all. Some years ago, it was yet possible to set up a not encrypted wifi, today it seems a forbidden knowledge; what makes me a little bit annoyed. Its driver is in staging and it does not support the "new" 80211 kernel api.

Comment: In the question please. Make it easy for people to help you

Comment: @ChrisDavies No. And I explain, why not: **because it has nothing to do to the question**. The question is only to set up a not encrypted wifi, my hw problems are offtopic here.

Comment: Shrug. If you won't act as our eyes there's no point trying to help

Comment: @ChrisDavies No, exactly not - exactly that misleading crap what I try to prevent, as I can find anywhere in the internet, particularly in wifi topics. You ask something and you get an answer to some very different.

Comment: I have found a post about disabling WiFi encryption and nmcli: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/620169/disable-wifi-security-in-network-manager/620229#620229

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an open AP, you need to set `wifi-sec.key-mgmt` to `none`:

```
sudo nmcli connection add type wifi ifname $WIFI_INTERFACE con-name $AP autoconnect yes ssid $AP
sudo nmcli connection modify $AP 802-11-wireless.mode ap 802-11-wireless.band bg ipv4.method shared
sudo nmcli connection modify $AP wifi-sec.key-mgmt none
sudo nmcli connection up $AP
sudo nmcli connection modify $AP connection.autoconnect yes
```

For general use, you need to check if your Wi-Fi card supports the AP mode:

```
nmcli -f WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP device show $WIFI_INTERFACE
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
```

`$WIFI_INTERFACE` is the Wi-Fi interface name, `$AP` is the desired AP name.